# Charting thousands of points with dojo

Tags: javascript, ajax, dojo, dojox.charting

I need to plot thousands of points, perhaps close to 50,000 with the dojo charting library. It works, but it's definitely very slow and lags the browser. Is there any way I can get better performance?

EDIT:

I solved by applying a render filter to the data. Essentially, I have a new item parameter called "render" which is set to false by my json source if the point is expected to overlap others. My DataSeries then queries for all points where render:true. This way all of the data is there still for non-visual sources that want all of the points, while my charts now run smoothly.

Psuedocode:

```
def is_overlapped(x, y, x_round, y_round)
    rounded_x = round(x, x_round)
    rounded_y = round(y, y_round)
    hash = hash_xy(rounded_x, rounded_y)

    if(@overlap_filter[hash].nil?)
      @overlap_filter[hash] = true
      return false
    end

    return true
end
```

x_round and y_round can be determined by the x and y ranges, say for example range / 100

Comment: Probably not with javascript. 50,000 DOM elements will be slow. Are all the points visible? Do you want people to click or interact or animate the points?

Comment: 50 000 items sounds like a bad idea - avoid doing stupid stuff!

Comment: All the points aren't visible, but I'm not sure how to remove points that are completely overlapped. I suppose if it was perfectly efficient all the hidden points were removed then there wouldn't be more than a few thousand points left.

Comment: Could you use a clustering algorithm, and show circles with the number of points in it until the user gets down to a certain zoom level? It would require a bit of pre-processing but could be done. Or you could show a density (heatmap) until the user has zoomed in close enough. Again, how much interaction will the user have with this and what are they trying to find out?

Comment: Basically, the user will be shown a graph of a scatter plot, along with a non-linear fit line, calculated by the server. Often times, there is error in data that skews the non-linear fit. I would like the user to assess the fit by visual analysis. They should be able to spot error in the data and then click/select a group of points to filter out and have the server re-calculate the non-linear fit. Sometimes they might need to zoom in on a section of the graph to better assess whether or not certain data may be part of the error, or just to see the a section of the cleaned graph in more detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this isn't probably exactly the answer you're looking for, but have you considered simply reducing the number of points you are plotting? I don't know the specific function of the graph(s), but I'd imagine most graphs with that many points are unnecessary; and no observer is going to be able to take that level of detail in.

Your solution could lie with graphing techniques rather than JavaScript. E.g. you could most likely vastly reduce the number of points and use a line graph instead of a scatter plot while still communicating similar levels of information to your intended target.

Comment: Of course this could be entirely non-applicable to your requirements. I apologise if that's the case.

Comment: I have thought about taking a random subset of the data. While this isn't a bad idea, it wouldn't work for this particular case. While clearly 50,000 points aren't needed for a 500x500 scatterplot, they are needed when zooming to a precise area. I suppose I could use ajax to pull points dynamically that fall within the zoomed range, but I would like a cleaner solution if possible.

Comment: Another issue is that the purpose of this graph is to find error in a scatterplot. If I randomly remove points, it's possible that the error will get removed and I won't spot the issue.

Comment: I went with this approach but made it smart as opposed to random. Works very well.